# Flutter iOS error "ld: framework not found installDir"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, runtime-error

I am a flutter newbie and I get this error when trying to run/build for iOS. I tried to clean Xcode, clean flutter, remove flutter, remove iOS folder, remove and re-download Xcode, but still.

No difference when trying to build from Xcode or vscode terminal.

what gets logged :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            7.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-07-28 17:04:40.105 xcodebuild[34247:421486] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-07-28 17:04:40.105 xcodebuild[34247:421486] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/sy/mftlbsd5489gl3102v5z7fwm0000gp/T/flutter_tools.RmfxI1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirho9O3B/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    ld: framework not found installDir
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/sy/mftlbsd5489gl3102v5z7fwm0000gp/T/flutter_tools.RmfxI1/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirho9O3B/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code


Error (Xcode): Framework not found installDir


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

sudo xcode-select --install
```

I checked my notes and found similar case in my experience.

Try to run these commands twice:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version
```

First run I got error, next time it works.